# How to clone a github repo in Windows using hg-git

Tags: windows, git, mercurial, clone

I am attempting to clone a github repo for the first time in windows.

I am following the instructions at https://hg-git.github.io/.  First I did

```
pip install hg-git
```

This worked fine.

I then tried

```
hg clone git://github.com/nicodv/kmodes.git
```

following the instructions for hg-git but that failed with

```
abort: repository git://github.com/nicodv/kmodes.git not found!
```

I also tried the same with https.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: "that failed"... that failed *how*? With what error message? With what version of python? Hg? and git version?

Comment: With correctly enabled hg-git (tip of) I can't see any troubles with cloning pure git-URLs - `hg clone git://github.com/nicodv/kmodes.git` is OK, contrary to git+https

Answer (score 0):

Note that there are issues around cloning with the current version of hg-git, like [issue 292](https://github.com/schacon/hg-git/issues/292) or [issue 307](https://github.com/schacon/hg-git/issues/307).

Check if you have the [latest version of dulwich](https://github.com/jelmer/dulwich/releases) (0.11.2-1 at the moment)

Comment: Thank you I will.  However what would a correct line be? I made up the version I tried :)

Comment: @eleanora your hg vlone should work. But knowing the exact error message as well as the version of git, hg, python and dulwitch you have used would help.

Comment: I added the error message to the question. I have Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 3.5+5) and Python 2.7.10 :: Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit).  I am not sure how to tell the versions of git or dulwich.

Comment: @eleanora would a `hg-git clone git+ssh://...` work? (as in https://github.com/schacon/hg-git/issues/152, as a workaround)

Comment: @VonC - without authorization `git+ssh://` will be no-no: "abort: git remote error: The remote server unexpectedly closed the connection.", BTW

Comment: @eleanora " I am not sure how to tell the versions of git or dulwich": speaking of which, do you have git installed? What `git --version` return?

Comment: I  haven't explicitly installed git. Do I need to do that?